# Mapsforge does not redraw cluster POI from Realm

Tags: android, realm, mapsforge

I use Realm for loading POI from DB. Next add this points to cluster realization by mapsforge.
This code works well:

```
 RealmResults<GasolineRealm> gasolineRealms = presenter.getRealm().where(GasolineRealm.class)
            .findAll();
    for(int i=0; i<gasolineRealms.size(); i++){
        geoItems.add(new GasolineGeoItem(gasolineRealms.get(i).getId(),
                gasolineRealms.get(i).getLocalizationRealms().get(0).getTitle(),
                gasolineRealms.get(i).getCoordinateLatitude(),
                gasolineRealms.get(i).getCoordinateLongitude()));
        clusterer.addItem(geoItems.get(i));
    }
```

It draw all POI on map, but if i use RxJava for Realm cluster never add POI on map.
Here is the code:

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(GasolineRealm.class)
            .findAllAsync()
            .asObservable()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<RealmResults<GasolineRealm>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(RealmResults<GasolineRealm> gasolineRealms) {
                    for(int i=0; i<gasolineRealms.size(); i++){
                        geoItems.add(new GasolineGeoItem(gasolineRealms.get(i).getId(),
                                gasolineRealms.get(i).getLocalizationRealms().get(0).getTitle(),
                                gasolineRealms.get(i).getCoordinateLatitude(),
                                gasolineRealms.get(i).getCoordinateLongitude()));
                        clusterer.addItem(geoItems.get(i));
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two would be nearly equivalent if you did this

```
     Subscription subscription = presenter.getRealm().where(GasolineRealm.class)
        .findAllAsync()
        .asObservable()
        .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
        .first()
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Observer<RealmResults<GasolineRealm>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(RealmResults<GasolineRealm> gasolineRealms) {
                for(int i=0; i<gasolineRealms.size(); i++){
                    GasolineRealm gasolineRealm = gasolineRealms.get(i);
                    geoItems.add(new GasolineGeoItem(gasolineRealm.getId(),
                            gasolineRealm.getLocalizationRealms().get(0).getTitle(),
                            gasolineRealm.getCoordinateLatitude(),
                            gasolineRealm.getCoordinateLongitude()));
                    clusterer.addItem(geoItems.get(i));
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Some thing wrong with ui thread in rx, because I receive all items and successfully save them in clusterer. http://joxi.ru/8234OjxckNYyAO

Comment: But it still doesn't draw item on map